# How can I set SendAs for all people

Tags: exchange-server, office365

I am using a help desk application and it uses an email address to send support tickets. I know how to configure exchange to allow one mailbox to SendAs another mailbox. However, I want to know how to set this permission so anyone (inside and outside) can send using this account. I am using Office 365 version of exchange.

Add-RecipientPermission  -AccessRights SendAs -Trustee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "inside and outside" ?

To do this in PowerShell, get all users whom you wish to add the SendAs permission:

```
$users = Get-Mailbox
```

**Customize the cmdlet below to filter your desired users or all users in your Office 365 tenant will be retrieved.**

Checkout the cmdlet documentation to filter your users:
[http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb123685(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb123685%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx).
Or use the "Where" clause.

Then use a loop to add the SendAs permission for each user:

```
foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Write-Host add SendAs permission on resource $resource to user $user
    Add-RecipientPermission "help desk account" -Trustee $user.Identity -AccessRights SendAs -Confirm:$False
}
```